# Translate a rectangle in a canvas using Gestureservice

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having a little problem translating a rectangle in a canvas.
What I want to do is to move the rectangle according to the user's finger position. Well here is my XAML:

```
            <Canvas Margin="100" Height="100" Width="300">
                <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="100" x:Name="rect" Height="100" >
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"/>
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </Rectangle>
            </Canvas>
```

What I did in the code behind is this:

```
private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((double)e.HorizontalChange != 0)
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, e.HorizontalChange - 100);
    }
```

When I run the application it performs really funny in a way that when I move the rectangle left or right it vibrates.
So anyone knows where is the error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and I found a better way to do this.
After I looked at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066%28vs.95%29.aspx), I did some modification and I got this in the XAML:

```
            <Canvas Margin="100" Height="100" Width="300">
                <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="100" x:Name="rect" Height="100" 
                           MouseLeftButtonDown="mouseDown"
                           MouseLeftButtonUp="mouseUp"
                           MouseMove="mouseMove"/>
            </Canvas>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
    bool isClicked = false;
    double rectPosition;        

    private void mouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isClicked = true;
        rectPosition = e.GetPosition(null).X;
        rect.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void mouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isClicked = false;

    }

    private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double position = e.GetPosition(null).X - rectPosition;
        double newPosition = position + (double)rect.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);


        rect.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPosition);

        rectPosition = e.GetPosition(null).X;
    }
```